# Dynamically "define" what environment variables (and their values) to pass to Docker container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I know that environment variables can be passed to a Docker container started with `docker-compose up` either on the command line (`VAR1=VAL1 VAR2=VAL2 docker-compose up`) or with an `.env` file. However, feeding the environment variables through on the command line requires them to be mapped in the `docker-compose.yml` file (under `environment` for the service to be started). For the example stated above, I would like to avoid having to specify `VAR1` and `VAR2` in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Is there any way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:** What I mean by having to specify `VAR1` and `VAR2` is the following (in the `docker-compose.yml` file):

```
services:
  dev:
    image: ...
    environment:
      VAR1=${VAR1}
      VAR2=${VAR2}
  ..
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a yaml file. You can parse and change it as you want.

```
# docker-compose.yml.input
services:
  dev:
    image: ...
```

And then something along:

```
python -c 'import os, yaml; dd = yaml.safe_load(open("docker-compose.yml.input", "r").read()); dd["services"]["dev"]["environment"] = [a: os.environ[a] for a in ["VAR1", "VAR2"]]; print(yaml.dumps(dd))' > docker-compose.yml
```